# Execute statements which is in CAT statement in R

Tags: r

I am trying to unzip 7z file which is located in "Zipfile_in" to output folder "Zipfile_out".

```
zip_7 = "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe"
zipfile_in = "C:/Data/Data Ectract/Report/2014.7z"
zipfile_out = "C:/Data Ectract/Report"
```

Actual system statement to extract is as below.

```
system('"C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe" x "C:/Data/Data Ectract/Report/2014.7z" -o"C:/Data Ectract/Report"',show.output.on.console = F)
```

To get the above statement i trying to construct and execute with below R statements

```
concat = paste0("system('",dQuote(l)," x"," ",dQuote(k)," -o",dQuote(j),"'",",show.output.on.console = F",")")
```

When i Run the below statement the statement i can not able to execute

```
cat(concat)
```

Any additional statement/modification required to execute i.e the 7Z file should unzip and stored in out folder **cat(concat)** ststement.

Answer (score 0):

To call system commands, the recommended instruction is `system2`.
Put the arguments in a character vector and call the system command as follows.

```
zip_7 <- "C:/Program Files/7-Zip/7z.exe"
zipfile_in <- "C:/Data/Data Ectract/Report/2014.7z"
zipfile_out <- "C:/Data Ectract/Report"

args <- c("x", zipfile_in, "-o", zipfile_out)
system2(zip_7, args)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , while i am trying to execute  "system2" ,the error i am getting is Command Line Error:
Too short switch:
-x

Comment: @san1 The command `x` doesn't have the minus sign.

Comment: Yes , now i have run witthout "-" for x command,the error i am getting is "Command Line Error:
Unknown switch:
-c"

Comment: @san1 Sorry, that was a typo, it's a `-o`. (Like in your original code.)